# Verification failed on ipod 6th generation

Tags: ipod

[image]
My daughter has the ipod 6th generation, it was working fine, then all of a sudden it started hitting random buttons, if there is a search bar or password area, it fills it with random letters, numbers, symbols all on its own before you can type in what your wanting to. It changes to different areas in the apps by itself, I was attempting to do a factory reset but it kept taking me to random different areas in settings. If I leave it off over nighthe, when I turn it back on in the morning it acts normal allowing me to do what I want except I keep getting this failure message when I try to bring up the messages, try to factory reset it, ect. Anywhere that requires the apple password. After about 30 mins to an hour, it starts the random stuff over again and you can't do anything. I have pictures showing the last back up to iTunes was on friday while it was connected to my computer trying to do a restore which I couldn't do because I can't shut off "find my ipod" 2 hours later it says it has never been back up, anyone have any advice??? Getting really frustrating

Comment: In the screenshot you have a Verification Failed error and your not connected to WiFi. Try connecting to a network before you try to sign in. This should't fix your problem where the iPod will enter random characters

Answer (score 1):

I Would start with restoring the iPod using Device Firmware Update (DFU). You can put your iPod in DFU-mode using these steps ([source](http://www.imore.com/how-to-iphone-ipad-dfu-mode)):

1. Connect your iPod to iTunes
2. Hold the power button (the one on the top) and the home button (the one under the screen) for approx. 10 seconds
3. The iPod will be turned off, release the power button but keep holding the home button for another 13-15 seconds.
4. iTunes will say it has found an device that needs to be restored.

You can now follow the steps in iTunes to restore the iPod. After the iPod is restored, configure it again and see the problem is solved.

If the problem is not solved, it's likely an hardware issue. You can visit a local apple store to send it in for repairs. It's probably good to make an appointment with Apple Care. Apple Care numbers for your country can be found on [this page](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201232)

Comment: Note: You will lose any data that has been put onto the iPod.